# Efficient row elements multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any efficient way to find the multiplication of every row in a matrix using numpy?
I mean, for example, if

```
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

then I would want something like np.sum(A, axis=1) just,

```
np.mul(A, axis=0) = [2, 12]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.prod` is what you're looking for.

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(np.prod(a, axis=1))  # Prints array([2, 12])
```

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I needed! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [multiply](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) function is an universal function ([ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html)) so you could do:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
result = np.multiply.reduce(A, axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[ 2 12]
```

Read the documentation on `reduce`, [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [nympy.prod](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html), exactly as you describe, i.e.

```
import numpy as np
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
np.prod(A, axis=1) # Gives [ 2 12]
```